# Index btree doesn't work

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have one table OrderDish that contains:

```
create table OrderDish(
    email VARCHAR(80),
    nOrd integer,
    totalPrice integer,
    sale integer,
    nameR VARCHAR(80),
    dayO integer,
    monthO VARCHAR(45),
    yearO integer,
    constraint c5 primary key (email, nOrd),
    foreign key (email) references Client(email),
    foreign key (nameR) references Restaurant(nameR),
    foreign key (dayO, monthO, yearO) references Data(dayO, monthO, yearO));
```

And I have a very common query that ask for the `totalPrice` sold by restaurant and by year.

```
select O.nameR, O.yearO, sum(O.totalPrice) as mytotal
from OrderDish O
group by O.nameR, O.yearO;
```

The results are:

```
+------------------------------+------+------------+
| nameR                        | yeaO | mytotal |
+------------------------------+------+------------+
| El Gordo                     | 2013 |       5699 |
| El Gordo                     | 2014 |       2793 |
| El Gordo                     | 2015 |      11457 |
| Eleven                       | 2013 |       7599 |
| Eleven                       | 2014 |       3724 |
........
```

I want to create some index to speedup this very common query. I have done so far this

```
create INDEX tot_per_rest_per_year 
    ON OrderDish(nameR) using btree;
```

but this doesn't speed up - the time consumed is the same.

Comment: You need to share the "common query" that is slow, along with the results when you run the query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it

Comment: forgot that sry, will edit

Comment: Did you try to make one index on both nameR and yearO?

Comment: yes, took more 30 seconds that whitout index, but should try using btree? i only know btree in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following INDEX could help you.

```
ALTER TABLE OrderDish ADD INDEX(nameR, yearO, totalPrice);
```

You are full scanning, even if there is `INDEX(nameR)`.

refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html

> Assume that there is an index idx(c1,c2,c3) on table t1(c1,c2,c3,c4). The loose index scan access method can be used for the following queries:
>
> ```
> SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 GROUP BY c1, c2;
> SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2 FROM t1;
> SELECT c1, MIN(c2) FROM t1 GROUP BY c1;
> SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE c1 < const GROUP BY c1, c2;
> SELECT MAX(c3), MIN(c3), c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE c2 > const GROUP BY c1, c2;
> SELECT c2 FROM t1 WHERE c1 < const GROUP BY c1, c2;
> SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE c3 = const GROUP BY c1, c2;
> ```

and,

> *" i only know btree in mysql "*

MySQL only supports B-TREE INDEX (except MEMORY Table which only supports HASH INDEX).

Comment: without index db need 0.9s, with you index i only need 0.22s..
i have one question, what is this index type? clustered,nonclustered, primary,secundary,dense,sparse?

Comment: @user3046650 good. I think this benefit from INDEX scan, which is smaller than whole data size and especially sorted by `nameR, YearO` that means **records are already grouped by nameR, YearO**. just need to SUM() So it's fast.

Comment: yes, i create using java one script to add 300k rows to table so i can check index benefit, and it works..
so, this is a clustered index cause they are groups my our index key, and uses bbtree, and my doubt now is if index is sparse or dense ;/